# 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid type in JSON write (_SwiftValue)'

Tags: swift, encoding

```
let params:[String : Any] = ["mobileNumber": mobileNumberTextField.text!,
                             "password": byteArrayPassword]

Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: params,encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON {
       response in
   switch response.result {
   case .success:
      print(response)
      break
   case .failure(let error):
      print(error)
   }
}
```

What am I doing wrong in this query?

Comment: `byteArrayPassword`: What's that? I guess that not an allowed value for JSONSerialization. It needs to be a String, a Number of null.

Comment: Unrelated but `break` statements (expect in `default`) are redundant in Swift.